# IIS cert stuck bound to external IP

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate

I set all my hosts to be bound to the same IP explicitly. Apparently that's bad.  I also didn't have SNI turned on.

As a result IIS is issuing the wrong cert.  `def.com` is getting the cert for `abc.com`.  Probably because I bound that one directly to the IP first.

`netsh show sslcert`

```
IP:port                      : 123.123.123.123:443
Certificate Hash             : <HashA>
//...

IP:port                      : abc.com:443
Certificate Hash             : <HashA>
//...

IP:port                      : def.com:443
Certificate Hash             : <HashB>
//...
```

It's probably something so simple, but I'm so green.

```
$ curl abc.com
200
test

$ curl def.com
curl refused.  Certificate is for abc.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem and it's pretty dumb, but I was definitely 100% right about the binding to the IP.

There were other sites on the same server with bindings that someone had bound directly to the IP address, too. Correcting those, and the `netsh show sslcert` suddenly stopped showing my IP address bound to a cert, and I knew right away that it was going to work, and it did.

It's also extremely important to make sure SNI is turned on for all SSL sites sharing an IP.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have SNI on, a HTTP server looks at the `Host:` HTTP header to decide which virtual host the connection was intended for.

If you are connecting over HTTPS, the server cannot see that header: it would need to decrypt the request first, but before decrypting, the server must identify itself, and it has no other option but to guess the default hostname, `abc.com` in this case.

This is an inescapable problem, and enabling SNI is the solution.

Comment: Yes. I know that.  I came from nginx/apache2.  The problem is, I no matter what I do, I can't undo it.  It's stuck on binding the IP itself.  I've already set Require Server Name Indication and set IP address to All Unassigned.  Before I had Require Name Indication set to false, and IP address set to 123.123.123.123(bit my real external IP).  That's actually what I think is causing the issue.  I remember seeing a dialog about switching all sites to the same cert, and I pasted the contents in IRC, but I can't get that message until I get back to my desk at 9am EST.

Comment: It's gotta be something so simple.

Comment: @Bluebaron you should know that Host header can be set for curl commands, https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2018/04/05/curl-another-host/